# ArcGIS 10.2: VB to Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser

I have the following VB code to produce a percentage in a field calculator.

`" [FIELD_1] / [Total]*100 "`

It works in VB. I've tried the following without luck.

`!FIELD_1! / !Total! * 100`

Can anyone translate this VB code to python?

Comment: Can we see a screenshot of your field calculator, with the python code in it?

Comment: Did you change the expression type to `Python`?

Comment: Yes. The expression was changed to python.

Comment: Hi. Here is a screen shot: http://imgur.com/QtkqxvS

Comment: Please be more specific than "*I've tried the following without luck*" or other things like "*it didn't work*" when asking questions. Unless the issue is blindingly obvious, that does not provide enough information for us answer you. In future, describe the results you actually got, whether it's an error message (include it) or incorrect values (provide examples). Please also provide more details,  such as the data types of the fields in your expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, in python, division between integers will produce an integer.  You will need to cast one of the variables as a float to produce the results you want.

```
float(!FIELD_1!) / !Total! * 100
```

Also, ensure the field you are running this in supports decimals - float or double.